# Is it known whether $\mathrm{NP \subseteq P/poly}$?

Tags: computational-complexity, np

It is not immediately clear to me whether this statement is true or false. Can finite restrictions of NP problems be computed in polynomial time?

Comment: No, this is not known, and this is not a research-level question.

Comment: The place to look things like this up is the complexity zoo. See https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#ppoly for what is known.